# Sefirotic dominance

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Background for question:
"One who is versed in kabbala knows how to act at the right time by knowing which sefira dominates at a particular time, and he cleaves to the light of the dominant sefira. He can then bring about the correct adjustment and harmonization of the sefirot through proper thought, speech and deed. In this way a person extricates himself from lack of awareness of G-d, which may be compared to sleep and death, and binds himself to holiness and eternal life, which is the mystery of Gan Eden. Thus the Crown of the Shechina never departs from his head.

[Translation and commentary by Moshe Miller from Tomer Devorah chap. 10.]"

My question:
I seek to further understand this issue and have in this respect the following questions:
What is the correct way to use the sefirotic dominance in daily life? Should one for example focus on acts of kindness on sundays (since chesed is in "control"), or are we to make special yichudim of divine names in accordance with the ruling sefira for a particular time?

Answer (score 5):

**What is the correct way to use the sefirotic dominance in daily life?**

To align one's activities with the spiritual "situation" (sorry, energy was too new age a word for me) at the time. In general, to know what that is, one has to be "One who is versed in kabbala" and if you are not, don't worry about it, that isn't where you need to be focusing your efforts.

There are, however, some more widely accepted and recognized practices that one can adopt that come from this idea, such as not studying Written Torah at night, not saying "Good Shabbos" (instead saying "a good one") after Shabbos Mincha and the like, that are brought in various Minhagim.

**Should one for example focus on acts of kindness on sundays ...**

The proper understanding of the Sefiros and Partzufim, etc. are much more subtle that these broad brushes. The idea is to have one's "thought, speech and deed" in unity with what is manifested spiritually, so it applies to all three of those faculties.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments yishai   in your opinion what is the best way to become versed in kabbalah?

Comment: @Levi, start with secondary sources, not the straight Kabbalah texts, and find a teacher who knows it. I know that isn't exceptionally helpful, but that is all I can offer.

Comment: This could be bettered with sources. "spiritual "situation" (sorry, energy was too new age a word for me)" couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Levi, one other thought occurred to me, is you could contact http://www.jnet.org/ and see if they can hook you up with someone to get you started. Not sure they will have the right fit, but the director is quite a matchmaker when it comes to these things. I would see that as a starting point towards Kabbalah, not the train to take you there.